# sourcetree: Why don't i see the changes that i made to a source file in the default sourcetree diff?

Tags: mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a local repo with a few files in them, when i press commit in sourcetree, you're taken to a window where you are shown all the changes you have made since the last commit.

I see those changes for all files except one- window_handler.cpp.
The file is around 64kb, and it is listed along with all the files, with an icon showing that some changes were made to it.
[image]

In the list you can see, by the yellow icon, that the file was modified, but in the region where the diff is shown comparing your changes with the previous file, i see 'Unmodified file'

If i check any other file, i see the diff. But i don't see diff for window_handler.cpp

I tried `hg status` I saw `M Window_handler.cpp`

But When I tried `hg diff -g` I didnt see the file name in that list.

I am relatively new to sourcetree.

Comment: Open a cmd prompt at the root of your repo and issue a `hg status`. Do you see the file with a `M` in front?

Comment: @Vince, yes i do see M before the file. So, hg detects that the file is modified. The problem could be with SourceTree

Comment: I tried `hg diff -g` on cmd, i didnt see the file `window_handler.cpp`, but i saw M before the file when i did `hg status`

Comment: I just saw that you are ignoring whitespaces. What happens when you uncheck the option?

Comment: No change. :) i have tried that before as well. Also, i have modified quite a few lines in the window_handler.

Comment: It is reported that files with changed permissions (on linux) could be considered modified, without having any binary change. Wonder if that could be an issue with Windows...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51560/discussion-between-vince-and-2am)